# recovering from a crash. data stored on a 3ware 9650SE-LP mirrored set

Tags: windows, raid, disaster-recovery, mirror, 3ware

So I'm hoping this will be very easy because my drive that failed is not part of my mirrored set. I had my OS drive go bad but my data drive ( my 2TB mirrored set ) is still ok. I just can't access it. I'm going to rebuild my OS ( switching from WinXP to Win7 ) for the rebuild. I just thought I should ask about any gotchas anyone might have run into because that mirrored set holds all my pictures and such so its very sensitive.

Thanks,
D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that finds this post my 3ware card performed like a champ. Replaced the failed OS drive, installed Win7, installed 3ware drivers and BAM! My data was safe and accessible. It couldn't have been simpler.

D.